# PowerShell - SendOnBehalf not adding all users in loop

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm making a script for new user on-boarding, not sure what's going on here, this block of code is acting strange.

The send-on-behalf line of code is only adding the last user in my `$delegates` variable, The `SendAs` and `FullAccess` add all the users in the `$delegate` variable.

```
$Fullname = 'Test User'

## Delegate receiving access to the other mailboxes
$Delegates = ("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5")

foreach ($Delegate in $Delegates) {
    #identity is the user(s) mailbox 
    #User is the user who will now be a delegate / have full access to the others mailbox

    ##Grants send on behalf
    Set-mailbox -identity $Fullname -GrantSendOnBehalfTo  $Delegate

    #Grants Full access
    Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $Fullname -User $Delegate -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $false

    ##Grants send as        ***** identity can give issues with username. try name or displayname ****
    Add-ADPermission -Identity $Fullname -User $Delegate -AccessRights ExtendedRight -ExtendedRights "Send As"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`-GrantSendOnBehalfTo` parameter of `Set-MailBox` cmdlet will replace the current one with the new one in you approach, hence it is having only last one as delegate. You have to do it in below way which will append the entries.

```
Set-mailbox -identity $Fullname -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{add=$Delegate}
```

see more help [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps).

Comment: Beautiful. Thank very much